# Get the currently signed-in user with AngularFire or Angular and Firebase Auth?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

The Firebase Auth docs explain how to [get the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users), in other words, to get the signed-in user's name, photo, etc. I can't get the provided code to run in Angular. Here's the provided code:

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Let's translate that into Angular.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})

export class HeaderComponent {

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public auth: getAuth,
  ) { }

    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        const uid = user.uid;
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
      }
    });
}
```

That is a mess and just crashes. Should I make an `Observable`?

Comment: This really belongs in a service. However, what crashes here exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Sometimes just writing out a question and then taking a break makes the answer become clear.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  auth = getAuth();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public auth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        console.log(user.uid);
        console.log(user.displayName);
        // ...
      } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
      }
    });


  }
```